# You don’t currently have permission to access this folder.

Tags: windows, windows-7

I recently was given Admin rights on my machine on work.

Unfortuanately when I am going through the directory structure I ket geting this message box:

[image: You don’t currently have permission to access this folder.]

If I hit continue, it works. But it is time consuming and it may be interfering with some of my development efforts.

Is there any way to just get permanent access to everything?

Thanks!

Comment: Try superuser or serverfault

Comment: superuser or serverfault  - what does that mean?

Comment: two cousins of stackoverflow. This question seems to belong there.

Comment: So thats why I get 2 down votes? Pretty unhelpful.

Comment: Thank you user877329 for the information.

Comment: (I did not downvote, but thought I'd explain.) StackOverflow is a site for programming (code) and programmers tools related questions, not general computer operating system, software, or hardware support. For those we offer another [se] site, [su]. The help center on each [se] site (available at the top of the page to the right of the `Search` area) has information about the types of topic that are appropriate for that site; here, the [help] explains that questions should clearly be programming related. I've voted to migrate your question to [su] where it's more suitable. Good luck. :-)

Answer (score 1):

UAC is disable ?

If not, I'll suggest to you to do this :

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
Put EnableLUA to 0 (if you want to reactive UAC put 1)
```

Others solutions : 
http://www.petri.co.il/disable-uac-in-windows-7.htm#

Comment: Thanks, read it over. Hesitant to do that in this environment.

Comment: Yes, it's true, it depends on what you would like to achieve but it's a good solution. If you want other solution, explain your case for us please ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make new folder,and than copy files.

Comment: Not sure how that will help. I need to have the message stop appearing through out my drive. A lot of these files need to be right where they are.